# How to animate a dialog to slide from the bottom of a screen to the middle without bounce?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to inflate a view that will be my "no network dialog". I created a custom layout that I now want to inflate and display. The conflict I am running into is that the animation does not work. I want the dialog to slide in from the bottom of the screen to the middle and then bounce at the end. Here is what I am working with.

styles.xml

```
<!-- animation for network dialog -->
<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_bounce</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Here is my slide_up_bounce.xml

```
<scale
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

<translate
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromYDelta="50%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

In an Utility class I have a method that looks like

```
public static void networkDialog(Context context) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogAnimation);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_network, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);

    ImageButton ibRefresh = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_refresh);
```

}

At the moment, the dialog displays instantly without the sliding or bouncing. How can I resolve this, or should I be trying to take a different approach to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you have all these tags in your slide_up_bounce.xml? The file must have a single root element: either an <alpha>, <scale>, <translate>, <rotate>, or <set> element that holds a group (or groups) of other animation elements (even nested <set> elements). From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Instead of using Dialog, it is better to use DialogFragment. For whatever reason, my Dialog implementation is correct, it just does not work with animations. Here is my implementation:

```
public class NetworkDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_network, container, false);
        v.setAlpha(0.5f);
        final ImageButton ibRefresh = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ib_refresh);
        ibRefresh.setClickable(true);

        ibRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MapActivity.rotateImageView(ibRefresh);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

And then I call the dialog with

```
NetworkDialog dialogFragment = new NetworkDialog();
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "ProgressDialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to pass a style as a `Dialog` parameter, as here:

```
Dialog confirm = new Dialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);

<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```